# JSON re-grouping with for each method in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angular and i want to re-group a JSON. Is it possible to do with `angular.forEach()` method?

```
[  
   {  
      "doc":{  
         "Title":"Main",
         "name":"Ajith",
         "Day":"03",
         "count":3
      }
   },
   {  
      "doc":{  
         "Title":"starters",
         "name":"Saji",
         "Day":"01",
         "count":39
      }
   },
   {  
      "doc":{  
         "Title":"desert",
         "name":"Sajeeb",
         "Day":"02",
         "count":63
      }
   },
   {  
      "doc":{  
         "Title":"Main",
         "name":"Suith",
         "Day":"03",
         "count":3
      }
   },
   {  
      "doc":{  
         "Title":"starters",
         "name":"Manu",
         "Day":"01",
         "count":9
      }
   }
]
```

I want the output should be like following.

```
{  
   "order":[  
      {  
         "Day":"01",
         "Title":"starters",
         "items":[  
            {  
               "name":"Saji",
               "count":39
            },
            {  
               "name":"Manu",
               "count":9
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "Day":"02",
         "Title":"desert",
         "items":[  
            {  
               "name":"Sajeeb",
               "count":63
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "Day":"03",
         "Title":"Main",
         "items":[  
            {  
               "name":"Ajith",
               "count":3
            },
            {  
               "name":"Suith",
               "count":3
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

To regroup with `angular.forEach()` method. 
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/9fwtm0a0/4/

```
var days = [];
arr.forEach(function(d) {
    var day = parseInt(d.doc.Day);
    var item = { name: d.doc.name, count: d.doc.count };

    if (days[day])
        days[day].items.push(item);
  else
    days[day] = { Day: '0' + day, Title: d.doc.Title, items: item]};
});

days.sort(function (x, y) {
    return parseInt(x.Day) > parseInt(y.Day);
});

var eventsinOrder = { order: days };
```

You don't really need the Angular forEach but you can easily substitute it in:

```
var days = [];
angular.forEach(arr, function (val, key) {
    var day = parseInt(val.doc.Day);
    var item = { name: val.doc.name, count: val.doc.count };

    if (days[day])
        days[day].items.push(item);
    else
        days[day] = { Day: '0' + day, Title: val.doc.Title, items: [item]};
});

days.sort(function (x, y) {
    return parseInt(x.Day) > parseInt(y.Day);
});

var eventsinOrder = { order: days };
```

Either way you go you will still need to make use of the sort function (or any equivalent) to perform the sorting while you're building this resultant object.